# When should `DateTime.now.utc` vs. `Time.current.utc` be used in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

In Rails, I'm a little confused on the guidance between when to use DateTime.now.utc and Time.current. There seem to be differing opinions inside the framework about which is best, particularly in different versions.

It looks like `DateTime.now.utc` produces a timestamp with a *UTC offset of zero*, while `Time.current.utc` produces a timestamp with a *time zone of UTC*. That seems like a subtle distinction but it's pretty important in many cases (e.g. DST calculations).

When should you use `DateTime.now.utc`, and when should you use `Time.current.utc`? Is there any reason to use `DateTime.now.utc` instead of `Time.current.utc`?

Comment: Can you give an example of where it makes a difference? Given that UTC doesn't have any daylight saving transitions, surely it only makes a difference when you start using other time zones... (I don't know Ruby, but I've done quite a bit of date/time stuff, so with more background I may be able to help.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't know if it makes a difference. (That's why I'm asking which one I should be using!) `DateTime.now.utc` first invokes `DateTime.now`, and then reverses the UTC offset to get to "UTC" time. So notice that it doesn't translate between _time zones_, but rather between _offsets_. Could that be problematic in edge cases, e.g., the infamous 1927-1928 example in Shanghai?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Unless you're actually in UTC, then `DateTime.now` and `Time.current` both produce a local time in something other than UTC. In other words, they seem to differ in their approaches about how they convert to UTC -- one does it by applying an offset straightforwardly; the other does it by actually redoing the time zone calculations in the new time zone of UTC.

Comment: Both seem to be somewhat broken, to be honest - getting the current UTC time via the local time leads to ambiguity, unless `Time.current` remembers its original offset from UTC as well...

Answer (score 58):

I think you should use `.current` instead of `.now`.

The difference of `.current` and `.now` is `.now` use the server's timezone, while `.current` use what the Rails environment is set to. If it's not set, then `.current` will be same as `.now`.

***Time.current***

> Returns **Time.zone.now** when **Time.zone** or **config.time_zone** are set,
> otherwise just returns **Time.now**.

***DateTime.current***

> Returns **Time.zone.now.to_datetime** when **Time.zone** or **config.time_zone**
> are set, otherwise returns **Time.now.to_datetime**.

Comment: how about Date.current and Date.today are these same?

Comment: What is the difference between `Time.now.in_time_zone` and `Time.current` ?

Comment: @pinouchon They are the same, both return instance of  `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`.

Comment: When is Time.zone ever _not_ set in Rails? I have commented out `config.time_zone` and I still get Time.zone equal to 'UTC' as it apparently sets that by default. So then, what is the use of using `Time.current` over `Time.zone.now`?

Comment: Just a pointer that it's DateTime.current not Datetime.current as in the above explanation. In case anyone is stuck there.  +1 on using DateTime.current over other options however.