# Is 10.minutes.ago using Time.now or Time.current?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, ruby-on-rails-4

"[The difference of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748804/1417223) `.current` and `.now` is that `.now` uses the server's timezone, while `.current` uses what the Rails environment is set to (`Time.zone`), if not set, then `.current` will act the same as `.now`."

When I do `10.minutes.ago`, is Rails using `Time.current` or `Time.now`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Time.current`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L366) (ActiveSupport 5.2.0)

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to use `Time.now` for `10.minutes.ago` or `10.minutes.from_now`, you can pass `Time.now` as parameter into `ago` or `from_now` method

ex: `10.minutes.ago(Time.now)` or `10.minutes.from_now(Time.now)`